# Zig 'expected error union type, found 'void''

Tags: zig

I have an array of a struct and I am being unable to sort it. The compiler returns `error: expected error union type, found 'void'`.

```
var general_purpose_allocator = std.heap.GeneralPurposeAllocator(.{}){};
defer std.debug.assert(!general_purpose_allocator.deinit());
const gpa = general_purpose_allocator.allocator();

var array: []Node = try gpa.alloc(Node, arr.len);
defer gpa.free(array);

... // Allocate the arr items to the new array

try std.sort.sort(Node, array[0..array.len], {}, cmp);
```

```
fn cmp(context: void, a: Node, b: Node) bool {
    _ = context;
    if (a.data > b.data) return true;
    return false;
}
const Node = struct {
    data: u32,
    value: ?u32,
};
```

if I remove the `try` of the `std.sort.sort` I get the error `Segmentation fault at address 0x0 (...)`

I am not very experienced in zig and clearly doing something wrong. (It is intended to use two arrays and not one). The code is running inside a test.

Comment: I don't see what's wrong with your code (aside from try on sort, it's obviously incorrect). How do you allocate items?

Comment: Yeah, so it was an error on how the items where allocated, I was checking mostly the code on the sort. I left one index free and fixed that and now the issue is gone. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer thanks to sigod's comment. It was indeed an issue on how the elements where being allocated and not on the sort as I thought.